# Sidekiq monitor no CSS and no Bootstrap in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I have a problem with sidekiq monitor - in development it works fine but in production it does not have any CSS working just displaying plain web page with no stilling on int! Does any body knows how to fix it please!!!!

I am using this version 
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sidekiq UI is not loading assets - 404 not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454898/sidekiq-ui-is-not-loading-assets-404-not-found). See also the [Sidekiq wiki for this issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-cssjsimg-assets-load-properly-when-i-go-to-sidekiqs-web-ui)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any idea how to use those suggestions with apache server? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

It works for me by linking gem assets to public folder like this:

```
ln -svf /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/web/assets /home/deploy/my_app/current/public/sidekiq
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution  for it is in `/config/environments/production.rb` to change from:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

to:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

found it 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953454/why-cant-nginx-find-my-assets)

Comment: This is not an Apache solution, that's Nginx